# Can't send inline image with SendGrid gmail. But works with nodemailer + zoho

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, nodemailer, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) to send embedded images in SendGrid.

### SendGrid

I cannot get the image to load in SendGrid.

[image]

```js
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
      to: 'somemail@gmail.com', // Change to your recipient
      from: 'company@company.com', // Change to your verified sender
      subject: 'SendGrid',
      html: `<strong>Some Text ${Date.now()}</strong><div style="border:10px solid blue;"><img src="cid:image123" alt="test image"/></div>`,
      files: [
        {
          filename: 'image.jpg',
          contentType: 'image/jpeg',
          cid: 'image123',
          content: `https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/536/354.jpg?hmac=ywdE7hQ_NM4wnxJshRkXBsy-MHlGRylyqlb51WToAQA`,
          disposition: 'inline',
        },
      ],
    };
    sgMail
      .send(msg)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

I also tried it with a base 64 string

```js
const buf = '_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD_4QguRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAEPAAIAAAAGAAAAngEQAAIAAAAJAAAApAESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAArgEbAAUAAAABAAAAtgEoAAMA.....
...
content: `data:image/png;base64,${buf}`,
```

### Zoho & Nodemailer

However the image does load using Nodemailer so I don't think it's gmail that's causing the issue.

I able to get inline images to show when using nodemailer with zoho:

[image]

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  try {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: <zoho_user>,
        pass: <zoho_password>,,
      },
    });
    const options = {
      from: 'Company Name <company@company.com>',
      to: 'someemail@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Zoho email',
      html: `<strong>Some Text ${Date.now()}</strong><img style="border: 10px solid orange;" src="cid:image123" />`,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: 'image.png',
          path:
            'https://i.picsum.photos/id/1069/536/354.jpg?hmac=ywdE7hQ_NM4wnxJshRkXBsy-MHlGRylyqlb51WToAQA',
          cid: 'image123',
        },
      ],
    };
    const sendZoho = async () => {
      return await new Promise((res, rej) =>
        transporter.sendMail(options, (error, info) => {
          if (error) rej(error);
          else res(info);
          transporter.close();
        })
      );
    };
    const res = await sendZoho();
```

How can I send inline images to gmail with SendGrid?